# What's Ruby syntax error here?

Tags: ruby, syntax

This is a simple code from rails project. But why Ruby shows syntax error here? In my humble opinion, all the necessary parentheses are present here.

```
link_to cart_remove_path(current_cart.item_for variant), class: 'text-danger', remote: true do
```

I know the way how fix this, like:

```
link_to cart_remove_path(current_cart.item_for(variant)), class: 'text-danger', remote: true do
```

But I cant understand why Ruby requires this extra parentheses?

Comment: what ruby version? This runs fine for me in ruby 2.3.4

Comment: ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin16]

Comment: Still can't reproduce. [This code](https://pastebin.com/CeL9aMkE) should be close enough to what you have, I think. And it doesn't fail for me. Try it. If it doesn't fail for you too, then we'll need a [mcve].

Comment: Show the error you receive at least, please.

Comment: @mudasobwa, the error is "unexpected keyword_do...". Has something to do with the value for the last keyword argument being a literal string or boolean. If you change it to a symbol/number/variable, it works. MCVE: `foo bar(baz 42), quiz: 'test' { }`. Ruby version - 2.3.3p222.

Comment: You should file a bug report, this looks like a parser shortcoming.

Comment: @ndn: how do you know it's _that_ error? If it is, how do you explain it being fixed by placing parentheses around 42 (because that's what allegedly happens in the OP)?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I know because I reproduced it. As for why these particular parentheses help the parser and why only with string/boolean values - I'm wondering the same myself. I agree with Stefan's sentiment that the parser is just being weird. I would understand it if the parentheses were around the `link_to` invocation, but that is not the case.

Comment: @ndn: ah indeed, block changes everything. Super-weird!

Comment: @ndn: at least, numbers behave the same as strings/booleans for me. But variables - it tries to interpret it as a method. I have no idea what's happening :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, hm, I tried again with numbers/symbols and I got the error. Not sure what I did test earlier. But for variables it does make sense that it would interpret it as a method call and pass the block to that *"method"* instead of `link_to`, hence no syntax error.